# How to avoid dummy variable trap for sklearn2pmml transformation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, pmml

When trying to create a sklearn2pmml pipeline I use the following code to do a custom mapping and then use PMMLLabelBinarizer to create the dummy variables. Things is, I want to avoid the dummy variable trap. Is there a way to do that using PMMLPipelines and avoid using any custom FunctionTransformer functions (I want to eventually convert the pipeline to a PMML file)

I couldn't find a way to drop my last column using a readily available PMML compatible function. (DataframeMapper is an sklearn_pandas function).

```
DataFrameMapper([
     ('Merchant', [CategoricalDomain(missing_values=[None, np.nan])
                    , LookupTransformer(map_dict, 'ZZ'), PMMLLabelBinarizer()
                   ])
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer` to limit the number of columns; the idea is to specify `ColumnTransformer.remainder = "drop"`.

For example, if your pipeline starts with a DataFrameMapper that is producing a 5-column matrix, but you want to retain only the first four columns:

```
pipeline = PMMLPipeline([
  ("mapper", DataFrameMapper[...]),
  ("slicer", ColumnTransformer([
    ("keep", "passthrough", [0, 1, 2, 3])
  ], remainder = "drop"),
  ("estimator", ...)
])
```

Support for the `ColumnTransformer` is available starting from the latest SkLearn2PMML version 0.42.0, so you might need to upgrade to it first.

Comment: Thanks, I think your solution would work but the "passthrough" functionality hasn't been implemented yet. When I try to create the pipeline it gives me an error


    NotImplementedError: get_feature_names is not yet supported when using a 
    'passthrough' transformer.

Comment: actually it looks like columnTransformer might just not play well with either pmml functions or sklearn_pandas. I will update when I have figured it out

Comment: Perhaps you need to update your Scikit-Learn version in order to have `passthrough` working. Anyway, `ColumnTransformer` seems more powerful and PMML-friendly than `DataFrameMapper`, so if there's a problem connecting the two, then you should consider getting rid of the initial `DataFrameMapper` step by merging its business logic into the second `ColumnTransformer` step.

Comment: FYI, technically this is the right answer but currently the sklearn2pmml conversion will return an error when you try to use 'drop' or 'passthrough' using ColumnTransformer